# GetLastInputInfo not returning dwTime

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, interop, user32

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class WindowsFunctions
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

    public static int TicksSinceLastInput()
    {
        var info = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        GetLastInputInfo(ref info);
        var lastInputTickCount = info.dwTime;
        return (int)lastInputTickCount;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct LASTINPUTINFO
{
    public static readonly int SizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 cbSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwTime;
}
```

However, on running, `info.dwTime` is zero.

Running in VS2019 IDE

**Update**:
I tried making `TicksSinceLastInput` not static it fails either way.
My failing unit test is now:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTicksSinceLastInput()
{
    var funcs = new WindowsFunctions();
    var ticks = funcs.TicksSinceLastInput();
    Assert.IsTrue( ticks > 0);
}
```

**Update**:
My code is now:

```
public class WindowsFunctions
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

    public  int TicksSinceLastInput()
    {
        var info = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        var result = GetLastInputInfo(ref info);
        var lastInputTickCount = info.dwTime;
        return (int)lastInputTickCount;
    }
}
```

result is being set to false.

Comment: I don't see you initializing `cbSize`. You calculate it, but I don't see any initialization

Comment: Pinvoke.net is always your friend: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetLastInputInfo.html

Comment: Thanks folks. I have it working now  I was not initializing correctly. Code is correct in PInvoke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration of `LASTINPUTINFO`, as it appears, comes from [PInvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/LASTINPUTINFO.html).
The struct contains a static int:

```
public static readonly int SizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));
```

It may look like it's defining the size of the struct, but it really has no practical purpose.

In your original code, the struct's `cbSize` member is not initialized and it has to be: it specifies the size of the structure itself; assigning it is mandatory.

The [GetLastInputInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo) function declaration is correct:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO info);
```

Its return Type is `BOOL` (defined as `typedef int BOOL`), not `BOOLEAN` (defined as `typedef BYTE BOOLEAN`).
`BOOL` is managed, it doesn't require:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
```

The declaration and initialization of the [LASTINPUTINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-lastinputinfo) structure can be simplified, to include a non-empty Constructor that initializes its members:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct LASTINPUTINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public uint dwTime;

    public LASTINPUTINFO(uint init) {
        cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<LASTINPUTINFO>();
        dwTime = init;
    }
}
```

Its members' Types are:

- `UINT cbSize`: `UINT` is defined as `typedef unsigned int UINT`, unsigned integer.
  It's a managed Type, it doesn't require (here) `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]`
- `DWORD dwTime`: `DWORD` is defined as `typedef unsigned long DWORD`, which is a 32-bit unsigned integer. Still managed, it doesn't require (here) `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]`.

Of course, specifying the marshalling Type doesn't hurt (when it's correct, that is).

---

Sample usage, using a Timer to show the elapsed milliseconds since the last Input:

```
// Better resolution than System.Windows.Forms.Timer
System.Timers.Timer sysIdleTimer = null;
// [...]

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);

    sysIdleTimer = new System.Timers.Timer() {
        Interval = 100,
        SynchronizingObject = this // Marshal events to the UI Thread
    };
    sysIdleTimer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
    sysIdleTimer.Start();
}

static uint GetLastInputTimeMilliseconds()
{
    var info = new LASTINPUTINFO(0);
       
    if (GetLastInputInfo(ref info)) {
        // Valid within 24.9 days of machine activity
        uint idleTime = (uint)Environment.TickCount - info.dwTime;
        return idleTime;
    }
    return 0;
}

protected void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Shows the Input Idle time in a Label
    lblInputIdle.Text = $"Idle Time: {GetLastInputTimeMilliseconds()} milliseconds";
}
```

[image: GetLastInputInfo IdleTime]